# embed video on android

Tags: android, youtube, mp4, embedding

I am trying to somehow embed (and loop/autoplay) a video onto an ASP.NET web page which will be viewed from an Android 4 tablet using a normal browser (default browser).

I cannot get the video to autoplay or loop. I have tried embedding from youtube, using the video as an mp4, converting it to html5 but still cannot get it to autoplay or loop.

What is the best way to embed a video and be able to autoplay and loop please?

Comment: Have you checked this page for supported video codec/format : http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html ? First is having a correct codec. You can use ffmpeg to convert your wideos.

Comment: no I haven't...so using any of the conventional methods (youtube embed/mp4 files) does not work? maybe I can convert it to MPEG-4 SP whatever that is?

Comment: For MP4, it works as long the file is `H.264 AVC` or `H.263` and it is loaded with a <video> tag. Then to autoplay and loop the video, you have to add `autoplay` and `loop` attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp & http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_loop.asp

Comment: hi guys...tried the above on android v 4.0.4 and it does not work :/ any ideas pls?

Comment: Post some code, please. (html & android)